# How to fetch arraylist data from database in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have stored my user inputs in the database through an `array list`. A user can take more than one seat as input in the database. And I want the user to book what `seats` I will `disable` those `buttons` on the next run.

My code is given below

```
public class Seating extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JToggleButton buttonA;
private JToggleButton buttonB;
private JToggleButton buttonC;
private JButton btnConfirm;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Seating frame = new Seating();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Seating() {
    initialize();
    connect();
    check();
}

Connection con, con1;
PreparedStatement pst, pst1, pst2, pst3;
ResultSet rs, rs1, rs2, rs3;

//For Creating Object Type array to pass the inputs from the button
public ArrayList<Object> buttons = new ArrayList<Object>();

//For Creating Button Type array to pass the inputs from the button
public ArrayList<JToggleButton> button = new ArrayList<JToggleButton>();

//For Creating String Type array to pass the inputs from the button
public ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

public void connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/airline", "root", "");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

    }
}

public void check() {
    String st, st2, st3, st4;

    st = buttonA.getText();
    st2 = buttonB.getText();

    try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from ticket_booking where Seats =  ?");
        pst.setString(1, st);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void initialize() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    
    buttonA = new JToggleButton("A");
    buttonA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (buttonA.isSelected()) {
                arr.add(buttonA.getText());
            }
        }
    });
    buttonA.setBounds(85, 56, 54, 44);
    contentPane.add(buttonA);
    
    buttonB = new JToggleButton("B");
    buttonB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (buttonB.isSelected()) {
                arr.add(buttonB.getText());
            }
        }
    });
    buttonB.setBounds(162, 56, 54, 44);
    contentPane.add(buttonB);
    
    buttonC = new JToggleButton("C");
    buttonC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (buttonC.isSelected()) {
                arr.add(buttonC.getText());
            }
        }
    });
    buttonC.setBounds(237, 56, 54, 44);
    contentPane.add(buttonC);
    
    btnConfirm = new JButton("Done");
    btnConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {

                pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into ticket_booking(Seats)values(?)");

                for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
                    pst.setString(1, buttons.toString());
                }
                pst.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Success");
                dispose();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {

            }
        }
    });
    btnConfirm.setBounds(143, 194, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnConfirm);
}
}
```

Comment: what object is this query returning `con.prepareStatement("select * from ticket_booking where Seats =  ?");` , map that object in `if (rs.next())` and add objects to arrayList

Comment: How can i apply this inside `if (rs.next())`?